# What does sign_in of devise do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am making rails api authentication using devise but could not understand properly what sign_in of devise is doing for us.

I have session controller with create method for sign in a user.

```
def create 
 user_email = params[:session][:email]
 user_password = params[:session][:password]
 user = user_email.present? && User.find_by(email: user_email)
 if user.valid_password?(user_password)
   sign_in user, store: false   /* exactly this line */
   render json: user, status: 200, location: [:api, user]
 else
   render json: { errors: "Invalid email or password" }, status: 422
 end
end
```

On rubydoc its description is written like this

> Sign in a user that already was authenticated. This helper is useful for logging users in after sign up. All options given to sign_in is passed forward to the set_user method in warden.

But it is not clear to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sign_in` is for when you already have a `User` object that you created or loaded/authenticated yourself and thus want to store in the session as the authenticated user for the rest of the current as well as upcoming requests.

If you look at the [source code for the default Devise `SessionsController`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L19) you'll see that it also uses `sign_in` to log in a user.

Devise is a layer over [warden](https://github.com/hassox/warden/), so you might want to look at its [documentation](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Overview) to understand this level of functionality. As the Devise documentation you quoted states, `sign_in` just calls the `set_user` method from warden. What Devise adds on top is a lot of convenience like the ability to work with multiple scopes and various warden authentication strategies.

Comment: what I understand here is sign_in store user object in session as authenticate user.

Comment: Does sign_in method make current_user available in rails?

Comment: what is significance of store: false here

Comment: The `current_user` helper accesses the stored user from warden, yes.  Adding `store: false` will not store it in the session but `current_user` will still be available for the remainder of the request.